# Stupid 'ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed'

Tags: json, angular, api

I cannot get this to work and I know I am missing something stupid.... No matter what I try I keep getting this error: "ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed" What the heck am I missing. I know it is something stupid but I cannot find the answer online anywhere. No matter what I try I always end up back at this error.

Service Code:

```
  SearchByTitle(title: string) {
    const url = `${this.url}&s=${title}`;
    return this.http.get<Movies[]>(url)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

I AM getting a response from my service. I can log it to the console. It is valid JSON data. My model matches my JSON response.

Component Code

```
  title = 'AngMDB';
  movieData: Movies[] = [];

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService){  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.GetData();
  }

  // Fetch movie data
  GetData() {
    this.movieService.SearchByTitle('star')
      .subscribe((res: Movies[]) => {
        this.movieData = res;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      },
      error => {
        console.log("An unexpected error has occured.");
      }
    );
    return this.movieData;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <button id="searchBtn" (click)="GetData">Search</button>
    <div class="movieList" *ngIf="movieData">
        <div class="movies" *ngFor="movie of movieData">
            <p class="movieTitle">Movies</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

API Response

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope","Year":"1977","imdbID":"tt0076759","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzVlY2MwMjktM2E4OS00…ctYzhkZGM3YzA1ZWM2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back","Year":"1980","imdbID":"tt0080684","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmU1NDRjNDgtMzhiMi00…ItZDNiZjU5NTU4OTE0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi","Year":"1983","imdbID":"tt0086190","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWZlMjFiYzgtMTUzNC00…MtZmNhMTczNTk0ODk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens","Year":"2015","imdbID":"tt2488496","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTAzODEzNDAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU1MTgzNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace","Year":"1999","imdbID":"tt0120915","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRhNjcwNWQtMGJmMi00…ItODVmMTdjNWI0ZDA2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0121766","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTc4MTc3NTQ5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTg0NjI4NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones","Year":"2002","imdbID":"tt0121765","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDAzM2M0Y2UtZjRmZi00…EtOTE3NzU5ZDVlMTU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUyOTg3Njg@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Trek","Year":"2009","imdbID":"tt0796366","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjE5NDQ5OTE4Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTE3NDIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Star Wars: Episode VIII - The Last Jedi","Year":"2017","imdbID":"tt2527336","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ1MzcxNjg4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzgwMjY4MzI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Rogue One: A Star Wars Story","Year":"2016","imdbID":"tt3748528","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjEwMzMxODIzOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzg3OTAzMDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"3612","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: please give what response you are receiving from api?

Comment: check the response. also, the 'let' keyword is omitted in the ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service returns object with movies array and additional info like "totalResults", you need to get movies array by taking "Search" field from your response object.
So just change

```
this.movieData = res;
```

to

```
this.movieData = res.Search;
```

in your GetData function

Comment: This worked ```GetData() {
    await this.movieService.SearchByTitle('star')
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.movieData = res['Search'];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.movieData));
      },
      error => {
        console.log("An unexpected error has occured.");
      }
    );
    return this.movieData;
  }```